# How to link a user ID with a to-do list in Firebase so that the list appears only to him when the user logs in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I want to use the following function to add to-do things from a list that is linked to a user.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toDoButton").click(function(){
    var lol = $("#somethingToDo").val();
    // $("#myList").append("<li> X " + lol + "</li>").addClass("deleted");
    $("<li> X " + lol + "</li>").addClass("deleted").appendTo("#myList");
    database.ref('users/' + useNumber).push({
      data: lol
    });
  });   
});
```

When I create a user, I do it with the following function:

```js
function recordUser(uid, name, surname) {
  var postData = {
    name: name + surname,
    data: "data"
  };
    
  var updates = {};
  updates['/users/' + uid] = postData;
  
  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Whenever a user signs in, I want only his to-do list to appear.
with the above functions, I can only create a NEW user with undefined ID.
Also I tried using the "data" field to update there the to-do-list

Can someone tell me how I can link user-id with the corresponding "to-do" list?

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my JSON tree
[JSON tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FlWs.png)

Comment: What does your Firebase JSON tree look like? Don't worry about the client-side functions yet, the most important thing is to have a solid database structure. Please post your current database structure, then you can get recommendations on best practices etc.

Answer (score 0):

use the user's `uid` as a key for his todo list node, so you can fetch it at login